# Simple sendMessageDelayed function in Android

Tags: android, handler, sleep

I am working on making a metronome that slowing speeds up as it runs and I need help with the sendMessageDelayed function.

First, I tried the Thread.sleep() But is was too laggy. I later I read there that it "Does not return until at least the specified number of milliseconds has elapsed".

Next, I read-about/tried using if statements with the  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() such as:

```
long nextbeep = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + waitms;

while(nextbeep > SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()){
    //wait
}//end while

mpbeep.start();
```

but it made the CPU run too hard and the beep was uneven.

**Edit: this is what worked for me:**

```
        bstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textviewone.setText("start");

            beepandwait();

        }// void onClick

    });// end b start listener

    public void beepandwait() {

    mSoundManager.playSound(soundnumber); //beep

    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(1), currentms); //wait

}//end beep and wait

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        beepandwait(); //and repeat

    }//end handleMessage

};//Handler
```

**Here is how to make sounds without lagging the system:**

```
package com.bgryderclock.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
private  Context mContext;

public SoundManager()
{

}

public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
     mContext = theContext;
     mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
     mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
     mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);         
} 

public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
{
    mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
}

public void playSound(int index) { 
     int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
}

public void playLoopedSound(int index) { 
     int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
     mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f); 
}

}
```